# Sql INNER JOIN with SELECT state is throwing an error

Tags: sql, database, select, inner-join

I have two tables:

One table is a "catalog" that stores a pageID, tableLocation, and a pageName.

The tableLocation is where the content for that page is stored (I have multiple areas of a the site... anyway).

I need to get data from the "tableLocation" so I want to do an JOIN so I can get all the data I need for the catalog and the needed table. Of course I don't know what table to look into without the "tableLocation" data. I'm trying to use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT p.pageID,p.tableLocation,p.pageName 
FROM pageCatalog p 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tableLocation 
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d 
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID) 
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
```

I'm getting an error, "Invalid column name 'pageID'"

If I replace the second SELECT with specific tableLocation it works. So the error is with the "INNER JOIN (SELECT..." but I'm not sure what the issue is. Any ideas?

------------- EDIT ----------
More detail:

for example pageCatalog has this

```
    pageID  tableLocation   pageName
    167     tableA          page1
    12      tableB          page2
    250     tableC          page3
```

in this example I have 3 tables. I need to pull data from table* but I need the tableLocation first. tableB has pageTitle. I need to join the two tables to get that data.

Comment: I know I'm already getting the "tableLocation" via p.tableLocation. I tried using an alias as the table name but that threw other errors.

Comment: from what it looks like you're trying to join a table on itself, is that correct? what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Also, the reason you're getting the Invalid column name error is likely because you're not selecting the pageID column in your subquery.

Comment: thanks Anders. Sorry about that formatting.

Comment: I have table (table1) that stores a pageID, pageName, and the table where the page data is stored (table2). I want to get the pageID, pageName, and content from the table that tableLocation specifies joined. I need the second SELECT to be the 'tableLocation' to get what I need.

Comment: I edited the issue with more information. Brian's suggestion didn't seem to get me where I wanted.

Comment: The problem I have is I'm looking at the second SELECT as like it's a variable. So, (in my head) that second SELECT should result in, say, tableB. I may be looking at this the wrong way then.

Answer (score 3):

```
(SELECT tableLocation 
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') AS d
```

I don't see a column named `pageID`, but you reference `d.pageID`

Did you mean to do this:

```
(SELECT pageID 
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') AS d
```

Answer (score 2):

In your inner SELECT you only select the `tableLocation` column, but then you try to refer to a `pageID` column as `d.pageID`. Try adding that column to the inner SELECT:

```
SELECT p.pageID,p.tableLocation,p.pageName 
FROM pageCatalog p 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tableLocation, pageID
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d 
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID) 
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `d.pageID`.  Your subquery aliased as `d` has only one column, `tableLocation`.  Modify it, like so:

```
SELECT p.pageID,p.tableLocation,p.pageName  
FROM pageCatalog p  
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT pageID, tableLocation 
 FROM pageCatalog  
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d  
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID)  
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's just no `pageID` in your sub query. Change it to this:

```
SELECT p.pageID,p.tableLocation,p.pageName 
FROM pageCatalog p 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tableLocation, pageID 
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d 
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID) 
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subselect aliased as `d` doesn't contain a `pageID`.

Try changing that to:

```
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tableLocation, pageID 
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d 
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have -

```
(SELECT tableLocation FROM pageCatalog WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d
```

then

```
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID)
```

The `d` table will only contain the column `tableLocation` at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You're not SELECTing pageID from the subquery. Try this:

```
SELECT p.pageID,p.tableLocation,p.pageName 
FROM pageCatalog p 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tableLocation, pageID
 FROM pageCatalog 
 WHERE pageName='PAGENAME') d 
ON (p.pageID = d.pageID) 
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
```

Or better yet, don't use a subquery at all:

```
SELECT p.pageID, p.tableLocation, p.pageName 
FROM pageCatalog p 
INNER JOIN pageCatalog d
ON p.pageID = d.pageID
WHERE p.pageName='PAGENAME'
AND d.pageName = 'PAGENAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did two query statements. First stored the tableLocation as a variable the second query replace the second SELECT with the variable. I wanted to avoid two queries but didn't see a way.